# Как убрать задержку перед запуском функции (SetInterval)

Tags: javascript, frontend

Как убрать задержку перед первым выполнением функции? Само тело функции у меня длится 9 секунд.
**Но нужно чтобы эта функция запускалась не через 9 секунд, а 3 секунды.** (внизу 9000 нельзя менять т.к это время выполнения тела функции). Заранее спасибо!

**Смысл кода:**
баннеры которые меняются бесконечно с определнным интервалом

```js
const regBanner = document.querySelector('.banner-reg');
const tourBanner = document.querySelector('.banner-tour');

 let changeBanners = setInterval(() => {
    let changeBannerReg = setInterval(() => {
        regBanner.style.display = 'none';
        tourBanner.style.display = 'flex';
        },3000);
        setTimeout(() => {clearInterval(changeBannerReg)}, 3000);
        
        let changeBannerTour = setInterval(() =>{
        regBanner.style.display = 'flex';
        tourBanner.style.display = 'none';
        },6000);
        setTimeout(() => {clearInterval(changeBannerTour)}, 6000);
},9000)
```

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос и добавьте код в виде текста, а не скриншота

Comment: "т.к это время выполнения тела функции" - настоятельно не рекомендую так уверенно считать что это всегда одно и тоже время будет :)

Comment: А я лично не понимаю смысл кода.. Почему нельзя внутренние `setInterval` заменить просто на `setTimeout`?

Comment: `setTimeout(() => { let changeBanners = setInterval(() => { ... }, 3000) }, 9000)` - вы так хотели или как? Ничего не понятно, перечитайте вопрос и отредактируйте его так, чтобы можно было понять о чём идёт речь.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы баннеры менялись каждые 3 секунды и делали это бесконечно.  Тело выполнения это 3000 + 6000 = 9000.

Comment: @Lonfich, подождите, где логика? Вы хотите, чтобы баннеры менялись каждые **три** секунды, откуда взялись **шесть** и **девять**?) Просто скажите что должно происходить в это время)

Comment: @De.Minov Сам не сразу понял, но суть логики такова: Есть 2 баннера, первый показывается 3 секунды, второй ждёт всё это время 6 секунд и общее время ожидания 9 секунд. Через 3 секунды первый закрывается и показывается второй, но второй уже ждал 3 секунды, значит из 6-ти секунд у него осталось 3, а у общего времени осталось 6 секунд. Через ещё 3 секунды, второй закрывается и показывается первый, а у общего времени осталось 3 секунды. И как раз эти 3 секунды и будет показываться первый баннер и т.д. бесконечно :)

Comment: Но если я не ошибаюсь, то после первого раза первый баннер будет показываться 6 секнуд, т.к. по окончанию первого общего ожидания первый уже показывался 3 секунды, а потом ещё будет ждать 3 секунды, пока его таймер не отработает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно каждые 3 секунды показывать по очереди два баннера, то можно это сделать в одном `setInterval`:

```js
const regBanner = document.querySelector('.banner-reg');
const tourBanner = document.querySelector('.banner-tour');

let showRegBanner = true;

setInterval(() => {
  regBanner.style.display = showRegBanner ? 'flex' : 'none';
  tourBanner.style.display = showRegBanner ? 'none' : 'flex';
  
  showRegBanner = !showRegBanner;
}, 3000);
```

```css
.banner-reg,
.banner-tour {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: none;
}

.banner-reg {
  background-color: red;
}

.banner-tour {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-reg"></div>
<div class="banner-tour"></div>
```

Но тут сначала первые 3 секунды ничего не показывается, если нужно, чтобы сначала был виден баннер сразу, то надо просто добавить в стилях изначально `display: flex`:

```js
const regBanner = document.querySelector('.banner-reg');
const tourBanner = document.querySelector('.banner-tour');

let showRegBanner = true;

setInterval(() => {
  regBanner.style.display = showRegBanner ? 'flex' : 'none';
  tourBanner.style.display = showRegBanner ? 'none' : 'flex';
  
  showRegBanner = !showRegBanner;
}, 3000);
```

```css
.banner-reg,
.banner-tour {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: none;
}

.banner-reg {
  background-color: red;
}

.banner-tour {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-reg"></div>
<div class="banner-tour"></div>
```

Comment: Жесть, я писал ответ, но не стал его опубликовывать и код первого сниппета один в один с моим :D Только я там вместо `showRegBanner ` проверял какой щас `.style.display`)

Comment: @De.Minov Мысли геният одинаково :) Ну и может автор захочет через `CSS` свойства делать проверки, так что твой ответ не будет лишним :)

Comment: Не думаю, что автор будет заморачиваться по коду, он и так запускает интервал и очищает его после выполнения, вместо того чтобы использовать один таймаут)) Да и с вашим кодом он ничем особо не отличается)

Comment: @De.Minov У нас же тут база знаний, не автор, так кто-то другой заценит ваш ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Написал такой вариант, который больше по смыслу подходит под описание вопроса.

Блок `REG` отображается 3 секунды, после чего скрывается и отображается блок `TOUR` на 6 секунд, и вот это всё действие уже зациклено.

```js
const regBanner = document.querySelector('.banner-reg');
const tourBanner = document.querySelector('.banner-tour');

const ToggleBlock = () => {
  regBanner.style.display = 'flex';
  tourBanner.style.display = 'none';
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    regBanner.style.display = 'none';
    tourBanner.style.display = 'flex';
  }, 3000);
};

ToggleBlock();
setInterval(ToggleBlock, 9000);
```

```css
.banner-reg,
.banner-tour {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.banner-reg {background-color: red;}
.banner-tour {display: none; background-color: blue; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<div class="banner-reg">REG<br>3s</div>
<div class="banner-tour">TOUR<br>6s</div>
```